# Ensure fixed number of decimal points when using Kendo formatting

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have played around with Kendo formatting. Specifically I am using `kendo.format` and `kendo.toString()`

I would like to fix the number of decimal points.

`kendo.format("{0:#.#%}",22)` works well, but it doesn't include a trailing zero for whole numbers. Ex: It doesn't give me 22.0%.

`kendo.toString(22,"p1")` can be used to ensure the decimal point, but it adds an undesirable space between the number and the percentage sign.(e.g.`22 %`).

Is there a way to ensure the trailing 0 in the formatted value (with no space before the percentage sign)? Or do I have to add code to remove the space manually?

I can easily remove it using a simple `.replace(" ", "")`, but I am just curious if there is a built in way to control it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use zeros instad of the sharp symbols. Thus you ensure there will be a digit rendered even if it is not needed.

e.g.

```
kendo.format("{0:0.0%}",0.22)
```

[Here](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/evAM) is live example, [Here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/numberformatting) is the documentation.